# Count Theft card as card in front on the player

Tags: saboteur-2

In the rules of the first Saboteur is specified that each player can have in front of them a maximum of 3 cards ( doesn't specify if blocking cards or other ).

In case I use a Theft card and I put it in front of me, does it occupy a slot for the number cards in front of me ? If the answer is yes, means that I can be blocked with maximum of 2 blocking cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be referring to this passage from the [rules](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Saboteur.pdf):

> At any given time, a maximum of three such broken tool cards may be in front of a particular player, but only one card of each type.

Given that each player has three tools, that is a meandering way of saying

> At any given time, only one broken tool card of each type may be in front of a particular player.

The point of the rule is that it's useless to break a tool twice. This has nothing to do with the Theft card.